# How do I install angular-cli on ubuntu 16,04?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

I'm facing an issue installing angular-cli locally. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS with following versions of node.js and npm:

```
node: v7.10.0 
npm: 3.10.10
```

I tried to install angluar-cli using the following command:

```
$npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
```

this worked fine and completed with following warnings:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform
    for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
    {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Now when I'm trying 'ng' command:

```
  module.js:472
   throw err;
   ^
   Error: Cannot find module 'abbrev'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular /cli/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:10:14)
   at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Comment: same probleme here.... did you find a solution?

Comment: @Maxiquester, no solution found so far. But I installed on my laptop following same procedure as I did on desktop. It's working fine on laptop.Both systems have same versions of ubuntu.

Comment: thank you for your answere, I managed it to install it not globally:
npm install @angular/cli@latest

that worked for me

Comment: I tried npm install @angular/cli@latest and thanks it worked for me now :)

Answer (score 8):

Just do this on command line:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache verify
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Found here:[Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir...](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17268)!

This fix the npm EACCES permission denied which brake the angular/cli install on ubuntu 17.04 for me.

Answer (score 2):

`npm install @angular/cli@latest`

Will not install angular-cli globally but it works for user.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this problem by learning this article : 
[Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory)

Answer (score 2):

To install it globally, use

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To install last version and globally, use

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

And if you are using Ubuntu 18.04, use

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```